# Using asihttprequest to fetch data based on http status code

Tags: ios, web-services, asihttprequest, polling

I am trying to connect my iOS app to a GET data from my web service everytime something changes. My current implementation is to use NSTimer and do a ASIHttpRequest but I don't like that polling implementation. Is there a better way to do it?

I am considering starting the request and lets it keep trying until the web service status code turns to OK (status 200) or perhaps a status code of "modified". How would I do this in a view controller?

Here is what I have so far:

```
self.asiRequest = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:self.barcodeUrl]];
[self.asiRequest setDelegate:self];
[self.asiRequest startAsynchronous];
[self.asiRequest addRequestHeader:@"Accept" value:@"application/json"];
[self.asiRequest addRequestHeader:@"Content-Type" value:@"application/json"];
int statusCode = [self.asiRequest responseStatusCode];
```

I know that if the request is successful, the delegate method `- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request`

I guess my question is, how do I keep an open ASIHttpRequest such that when the web service returns "modified", it calls a GET request and then keep an open connection again? This has to be asynchronous and not running on a UI thread as I don't want to keep my app hanging.

Thanks much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this without having to do much on the client-side is to get your web service to send a `Location:` header through when it returns "modified", pointing to the URL you want to `GET` with the new content. If the URL to monitor is different depending on e.g. user ID or the area of the app you are in, make a monitor script where you can pass in `GET` params to configure what exact URL should be returned to you when "modified" is returned.

The `ASIHTTPRequest` will then automatically `GET` the content at the new `Location:` and you can reschedule it in `requestFinished:` to the monitor URL again, knowing that the response (if not empty/"Not Modified") will ALWAYS be new data since the redirect to new data happens behind-the-scenes.